# Setup automated build\deployments to my Azure VM using VSTS?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

I have my source control in Visual Studio Team Services and push my code via web deploy to my Azure VMs. Just going thru several Azure related articles, it's hard to figure the easiest way to setup continuous delivery where the latest code is pushed to VMs per developer check-ins?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some of the deployment articles in VSTS? You can setup continuous deployment in a more flexible way (to VMs for instance) using Build and RM in VSTS. 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/examples-index